# How to queue a (macro)task in the JavaScript task queue?

Tags: javascript, task, event-loop

What is the most straight-forward and direct way to [queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) in the browser event loop, using JavaScript?

Things that **don't** work:

- [`window.setImmediate(func)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate): Non-standard.
- `window.setTimeout(func, 0)`/`window.setInterval(func, 0)`: [Browsers throttle timers to ≥ 4ms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts_throttled_to_%E2%89%A5_4ms)
- `new Promise(r => r()).then(func)`: That queues a microtask, not a task.

Comment: Use settimeout with 0. Them minimum is a nonzero minimum

Comment: @JaromandaX [That doesn't work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts_throttled_to_%E2%89%A5_4ms)

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't? Documentation states *if this argument is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle.*

Comment: @JaromandaX 1. The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) says that if `setTimeout` is called more than 5 times, the timeout is set to 4 (ms). "If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then set timeout to 4."    Try it yourself: `{let x=performance.now(); (function f() { const n=performance.now(); console.log(n-x); x=n; setTimeout(f, 0) })();}`.

Comment: All the tools we have like Promises, Mutation Observer, Next tick etc allow you to meddle with microtask. All other tools like requestAnimationFrame, setImmediate, setTimeout etc allow you to meddle with the macrostack (the stack above microtask.) I dont think, there is a way to change the way the main event loop works. However, the way event loop works is that, if microtasks queue more microtasks the loop is considered not finished, so you can go ahead with Promises, I am sure it would be indistinguishable from queing them directly below the main stack.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin They are not indistinguishable, though. A microtask loop will make the event loop never reach the tasks, pausing rendering, event handling, etc...

Comment: @D.Pardal If UI blocking is what you mean, stacking them in the task queue does EXACTLY that. That's why they are indistinguisable. If the loop doesn't end, it is UI blocking, if the microtasks does not end, it is ALSO Ul blocking.

Comment: I would recommend whatching [this video about the event loop](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0) *before* commenting.

Comment: That video is exactly what you don't get.

Comment: @D.Pardal OK - I did not know that part of the spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MessagePort.postMessage`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#window-post-message-steps) does just that.

```
onmessage = e => handleMessage;
postMessage("","*");
```

You can even use a [MessageChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel) if you want a less intrusive mean:

```
const channel = new MessageChannel();
channel.port1.onmessage = handleMessage;
channel.port2.postMessage('');
```

This is currently the only API that does *queue a task* synchronously, all others implying at least some *in parallel* execution.

Maybe one day we will have a [`scheduler.postTask`](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md#main-thread-scheduling-prioritized-posttask-api) method, which would even allow us to specify some priority for our tasks, but that's for the future only...

Comment: I was expecting this answer, as [it's what setimmediate.js uses](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate#postmessage). Let's see if someone knows a better way.

Comment: That's the most straigtforward way. Really, it's currently the only API we have which really is just **synchronously** queuing a task.

Comment: I was just waiting for more answers. They didn't come. It seems that really is the only way then.

Comment: Considering transferable objects are buffers,ports and canvases and we pass strings back and forth, is this going to be more suited and performant for ordinary task queuing compared to Promises for instance ?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcinI not sure what you mean... serializing an empty string is nothing. Creating a Promise and forcing the entrance to the microtask endpoint is more work. No need to transfer anything, even though transferring is once again nothing.  So..  yes it's better than Promises because Promises don't *queue a task* for one, and because a queuing an empty message is like almost nothing in terms of computations.

Comment: You need to "pass" the result from the previous computation from port1 to the other message handler of the port2 (even if empty string), even if both ports end up in the same window. This involves 2 extra steps of calling onmessage handlers as opposed to just executing the next task. Do you have a working fiddle and an accompanying jsperf to prove your point ? Because you made the claim

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I really don't understand your point, and I fear you actually don't understand the question here... A Promise doesn't call *queue a task*, it doesn't exit the current event loop iteration. If you wish, you can try `const stoopidLoop = () => Promise.resolve().then( stoopidLoop ); stoopidLoop()`. This will block your browser just like a `while(true){}` loop, because it will never let the event loop to actually loop, itwill just make it grow synchronously. So we can't compare both because only *postMessage* does what's being asked, that is to *queue a task*.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin in comparison, you can also try `onmessage = e => postMessage('','*'); postMessage("");` it will probably make your CPU spin a bit more, since indeed it will never be able to idle, but still your page will be responsive, all the other events will have their chance to run and more importantly, the browser will be able to *update the rendering*.