# Is there a way to tell the event loop to process next message in ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I know one must not block the loop, I know use call backs, and I know ES6 `await`. The more I research this the more it reaffirms it.

But sometimes your hands are tied. Is there a way to tell JavaScript, please go check on your event queue, and service those, then come back here before  continuing execution.

Something like [inspired by the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

```
if (queue.hasNextMessage()) {
  queue.processNextMessage()
}
```

There are similar threads about use datetime to wait a duration, but I don't know how the long other event thread will take, been looking at polling the promise status, but it appears to be a dead end.

The context is I have to override a validation callback. The caller of the callback does not wait for a promise to resolve (That I cant change).

Here is the test setup showing the concept. I have made a few attempts, but none of them work because they are always stuck in the main loop.

```
// The validate function depends on a fetch call which takes time.
// Free to change this.
function validate() {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {console.log(data); return true;})
        .catch(msg => {console.log(msg); return false;})
}

// Cannot change this function, I am not in control of it
function CallValidate() {
    console.log("Validation Result: ", Boolean(validate()));
}

// This is the setup for when test passes
let url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json';
CallValidate();

// This is the setup for when test fails
// This currently fails because the promise objects is being evaluated
// to true, instead of waiting for its response.
url = 'http://DUMMY.NOT.WORKING.URL';
CallValidate();
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) While some of the answers discuss ES6+ solutions, you can find the answer to this question.

Comment: Yes if you know what you are waiting for to be handled you can use `promiseOfTheThingYouAreWaitingFor.then(value => {/* code */})`

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes that is using a call back. The problem is I am overiding a callback that will not wait for a promise to be fufilled before returning.

Comment: @run_the_race It sounds like you need to make it wait for the promise then. Could you add some code of what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I added some code I have been working with to illustrate it (I cut out all the failed attempts and dead ends).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell JavaScript, please go check on your event queue, and service those, then come back here before continuing execution.

No, but you can do something very similar: divide your computation into several tasks. In Node.js, you can use `setImmediate()` to queue a task. In the browser, you can use messages, as outlined by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61574326/9253414).

Example:

```js
function setImmediate(callback) {
  const channel = new MessageChannel();
  channel.port1.onmessage = () => {
    callback();
  };
  channel.port2.postMessage("");
}

console.log("Task 1");
setImmediate( () => {
  console.log("Task 2");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that `await` looks like a gotcha (not ES5) , but I don't fully understand if I can get around it, busy researching MessageChannel now.

Comment: Thanks for the change. From what I can see, The channel object can have calls backs attached to it when it receives a message. This does not block the current thread. Fair enough you did  prefix your answer with "No". If one could wait for a message to arrive, and while waiting the receiver was free to execute in the main loop, then this would help.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean(validate())` will always evaluate to `true`, because `validate` returns a `Promise` which is a truthy value no matter what it resolves to.

If you can't change `CallValidate`, you might still be able to lift up the `fetch` call. But I'm not sure if that's an option for you.

```
async function validateUrl(url) {
  const valid = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {console.log(data); return true;})
    .catch(msg => {console.log(msg); return false;});

  function validate() {
    return valid;
  }

  function CallValidate() {
    console.log("Validation Result: ", Boolean(validate()));
  }

  CallValidate();
}

// assuming you are in async function context
await validateUrl('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json');
await validateUrl('http://DUMMY.NOT.WORKING.URL');
```

If moving the function is also no option I would ditch the `CallValidate` code and either write something yourself, or pick another library/helper/etc that does handle asynchronous functions (with promise return values).