# Increment value in time

Tags: javascript

I am looking to increment the value of "time" with 0.01 each 10 miliseconds until it gets to the desired value. Right now it just increases it instantly to the conditioned value.

```
var time = 0;

function animate() {
  decreaseIncrement = -0.78;
  increaseIncrement = 0.78;

  if (
    (document.getElementById("but5").onclick = function () {
      if (time < increaseIncrement) {
        do {
          time += 0.01;
        } while (time < increaseIncrement);
      }
    })
  )
    if (
      (document.getElementById("but3").onclick = function () {
        if (decreaseIncrement < time) {
          do {
            time -= 0.01;
          } while (decreaseIncrement < time);
        }
      })
    )
      increaseIncrement = time + increaseIncrement;
  decreaseIncrement = time + decreaseIncrement;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2epqg1wc/1/

Comment: You may need to make your functions async and add `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10))` to your loops to block the next iteration of the loop from running.

Comment: because a while loop will sit there until it is done.... You are going to have to use an interval/timeout

Comment: `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10))` would paus for at least 10ms but the time could be larger. So if you want to have a smooth animation neither this nor `setInterval` will work reliably in combination with `time += 0.01` @AsyncAwaitFetch

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that problem using `setInterval` which repeatedly runs a task every `x` milliseconds until you cancel it. Below code reduces the value to 0 in 0.01 steps with a step performed every 10 milliseconds.

```js
var value = 1.0;
var decrement = 0.01;


function decreaseAnimation() {
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    value -= decrement;
    console.log(value);
    if (value <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 10);
}

decreaseAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

- requestAnimationFrame (rAF)
- setTimeout/setInterval (sTo)
- messageChannel

The first 2 options are more straightforward but they will lack the precision, because rAF fires every 17 milliseconds (assuming 60Hz) and sTO will fire at most 4ms after 4 successive recursions. Usually rAF is preferred over sTo because of better reliability in timing of firing these callbacks. Use sTO as a fallback if rAF is not supported.

Here is an implementation from a [library](https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX) for similar purposes:

```js
var rafx = require("rafx");
rafx.async({ //create a ledger object to store values
   curr_time:0,
   desired:Math.random(),
   frames:0
}).animate(function(obj){ 
    //obj is the ledger above
    //increment obj.frames here if you want to
    return obj;
},).until(function(obj){
    obj.frames++;
    obj.curr_time = obj.frames * 17 / 10 * 0.01;
    return obj.curr_time >= obj.desired;
}).then(function(obj){
    console.log("sequence ended with values:" + JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

You can copy paste the code above [here](https://npm.runkit.com/rafx) and test it.

The last option uses [`MessageChannel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574088/how-to-queue-a-macrotask-in-the-javascript-task-queue) to post message between ports, which gives extremely high precision because it is fired at the next event loop. You can combine this with [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to determine whether to increment your `time` or not.

**Disclosure:** I am the author of the aforementioned lib.